# From application Insight how do I query function calls that are triggered by retry policy?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I know for the event-triggered azure function, it has a retry policy turned on by default.

Wondering in the application Insight log, how do I query all that retry calls out? I looked at "traces" and "requests" table, there is no column can indicate the function call is triggered by retry policy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the retry policy logs, I would like to suggest you to Check in Invocations Section Of monitor Section Of Functions as below:

[image]

Firstly, go to your function app then click on functions and then on Invocations then on Date and the clear message opens as above.

As of my understanding Event Grid Trigger restarts every time a new event occurs (i.e it triggers because of retry policy). If a Function gets triggered, its details are stored in Invocations Section of Function App.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery) for further understanding on Retry policy and dead letter events.

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja, I can't use monitor as it only show last 20 runs I believe. I will need to query some details from the appInsight log for a history retry execution which might happen a few days ago.

Comment: You can Click on **Run query in application insights** and change the timestamp, [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465790/azure-function-log-that-is-older-than-20-days) for doing that.

Comment: I know that, however, what I need is to query runs by whether it is triggered by retry. Each day our function got invoked few hundred times, I might need to query all the retry ones out.